# Can I use a Sanyo tv as raspberry pi display?

Tags: pi-2, display, connection, kali

So I have a decently old Sanyo tv laying around, and I want to put it to some use. I intend on using it as a display for my raspberry pi. All in all I was just wondering whether such a task is possible or not? Also if anyone is kind enough to answer, how would I go about doing such a thing?

EDIT: I plugged it into the Component 2 yellow jack, but nothing is happening. The screen is blue with the Component 2 on the upper left corner.

**UPDATE** with info from comment:
There are audio/video input(circular holes) with the colors red, yellow and white if I am seeing correctly. Then there is an identical three holes next to it, with a label that I cannot read(it is covered in dust). There are inputs in a cd player and cassette player(very old) but I don't think that will matter.

Comment: What inputs does it have?

Comment: There are audio/video input(circular holes) with the colors red, yellow and white if I am seeing correctly. Then there is an identical three holes next to it, with a label that I cannot read(it is covered in dust). There are inputs in a cd player and cassette player(very old) but I don't think that will matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the yellow RCA jack is probably a video input. Connect it to the yellow RCA jack on the Pi.

You just need a [single RCA (or "phono") cable](http://www.cables2u.co.uk/images/products/Single_rca_cable.jpg)

(The white and red jacks are probably left and right audio inputs respectively.)

Comment: I tried this and then noticed there are three sets of three red, yellow and white jacks each in different orders. The ones on front when plugged in from the raspberry pi to the tv cause the screen to flicker, but no display shows up. I have the cables with the colors red, yellow and white previously connected to the cassette player.

Comment: Are you selecting the right input on the TV? There should be an "input" or "source" button on the remote to cycle between the various input options. Sounds like the front inputs are a good bet.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a AV Jack. Use a composite converter. Then activate composite video from /boot/config.txt.(Uncooment the line)
or an easy way is from terminal

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then go to advanced option and activate composite
And reboot.
Composite to AV converter looks like 3.5 mm jack at one end , and other end have 3 outputs. RED,WHITE and YELLOW. Yellow is the video jack. And other two is audio.